# Name attribute does not get rendered in Liferay Portlet

Tags: java, request, liferay, liferay-6

I am creating a simple Liferay Portlet and I cannot manage to get a name given in an input Box to get rendered. The main Portlet class is:

```
public class MyHelloWorldPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

public void init() {
    editJSP = "/html/myhelloworldportlet/edit.jsp";
    viewJSP = "/html/myhelloworldportlet/view.jsp";
}

public void processAction(
        ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    String name = actionRequest.getParameter("name");
    PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();

    prefs.setValue("Name", name);
    prefs.store();

    actionResponse.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
}

public void doEdit(
        RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    include(editJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
}

public void doView(
        RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    String defaultValue = "";
    String name = prefs.getValue("NAME", defaultValue);

    renderRequest.setAttribute("ATTRIBUTE_NAME", name);

    include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
}

protected void include(
        String path, RenderRequest renderRequest,
        RenderResponse renderResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    PortletRequestDispatcher portletRequestDispatcher =
        getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path);

    if (portletRequestDispatcher == null) {
        _log.error(path + " is not a valid include");
    }
    else {
        portletRequestDispatcher.include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}

protected String editJSP;
protected String viewJSP;

private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(MyHelloWorldPortlet.class);
```

}

The edit.jsp file is:

```
<form action="<portlet:actionURL/>" method="post" name="<portlet:namespace/>fm">
<label for="<portlet:namespace/>name">Name:</label>
<input name="<portlet:namespace/>name" type="text">
<br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Add Name">
</form>
```

The view.jsp file is:

```
<%
String name = (String)request.getAttribute("ATTRIBUTE_NAME");
%>


<p>Hello <%= name %>!</p>
```

The problem is that the output on the view is always Hello!. Not any name is passed to the output although the user enters one in the input Box. Why?

Comment: did u check that whether your processAction method is being called or not??(i .e System.out.println("");)

Comment: Are you getting any value in `actionRequest.getParameter("name");`? On the other hand, i'm not sure if setting the preference with "Name" and recovering it with "NAME" is right.

Comment: @Dani: where can I check it? In jsp file or in Portlet class?

Comment: You can simply print the value of the variable "name" after getting from `actionRequest`

Comment: @LuckyBoy: How can I check that? I am very new to Liferay and am ignorant of many (basic) matters.

Comment: you check just try to print syso("name "+actionRequest.getParameter("name"));  inside your processAction method.

Comment: Yes, it prints the name entered by the user. I assume therefore, there is something wrong in my view.jsp file Or this request.getAttribute()?

Comment: you are trying to get " String name = prefs.getValue("NAME", defaultValue);"  but u are saving  it like this " prefs.setValue("Name", name);" ..  check this..i guess it should be Name instad of NAME

Comment: Finally that was the problem. In processAction I had used in setValue method "NAME" and then in doView I tried to retrieve it as "Name". Due to being new to Liferay, I though it was a config problem, or something lacking in xml etc.

Comment: ok...Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your doView method:

```java
public void doView(
    RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
throws IOException, PortletException {

    PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
    String defaultValue = "";
    // you need to recover the preference using the same name you used when you set it
    String name = prefs.getValue("Name", defaultValue);

    renderRequest.setAttribute("ATTRIBUTE_NAME", name);

    include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
```

}

The rest of your code is fine, in my opinion.

Comment: As I state in my last comment the problem was merely the difference between "NAME" and "Name".